# How to Resize Cells in WPF Grid

Tags: wpf, grid, resize, textblock, cells

After constructing a Grid and adding Rows and Columns to it, how can modify the dimension of each Cell. I am not able to locate any property that would help me to achieve this.

As additional note, I am adding TextBlocks to each of the cell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the column width and row height within your ColumnDefinition and RowDefinition tags, or if you wish to have the cells in a less uniform arrangement you can set the ColumnSpan (might be ColSpan, it's been a while!) and RowSpan properties of each cell to create cells that span more than one row or column.

Answer (score 2):

Do you want modify cells dimensions at runtime? If yes take a look at [GridSplitter](http://www.wpftutorial.net/GridLayout.html).

Comment: So GridSplitter is way to go. Take a look at link I have posted. There is an example of using GridSplitter.

Comment: Looks like I have not conveyed my query properly. Actually I don't want user to control the size rather use code to change.

Comment: Use Grid.RowDefinitions and Grid.ColumnDefinitions collections. You can then use RowDefinition.Height or ColumnDefinition.Width to change cell dimensions at runtime.